# Closing a question based on the 'localization' of the answer

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I recently helped someone troubleshoot a question that (I don't think) was in and of itself inherently 'localized' [Can't add myself as an administrator on my own Facebook page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44776/i-cant-add-myself-as-an-administrator-on-my-own-facebook-page?noredirect=1#comment35677_44776). (My theory, here, being that there is a general way/solution for adding yourself as a Facebook page admin.) However, the solution we discovered via comments was that the individual asking the question was using the wrong email address to log in to Facebook.

So, essentially, the problem has been solved (though the question has no 'Answer') but the solution is unlikely to help anyone else in the future (i.e. is localized).

Is this an appropriate situation in which to flag (or, for those who have the privilege, vote) for closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally if you have the privilege you should close vote. Because there aren't that many close voters, I don't think any mod minds if you flag their attention.

Just try to be descriptive when flagging

I have closed the question.

Comment: Thx - I just wasn't sure if this was a basis for closing so I wanted to check before making any moves